# Python: input 4 digits using input and a while loop

Tags: python, loops

Ask the user to input 4 digits using input and a while loop. The loop should keep running until the user inputs q.  Make sure the user never sees a Traceback if an error occurs. Here's an example output:

```
Please enter four digits. Enter 'q' to quit.
Enter four digits: 3210
Enter four digits: 3333
Enter four digits: 332
Sorry, you inputted 3 digit(s).
Enter four digits: 32AB
Please input only numerical values.
Enter four digits: q  <- This quits the program.
```

My codes are below:

```
while True:
try: 
    number = int(input("Please enter four digits: "))
except ValueError: 
    print("Please input only numerical values ")
if number > 9999:
    print("Please enter four digits")
elif number <1000:
    print("Sorry, you inputted 3 digit(s) ")
elif number < 0:
    print("Please enter four digits:")
else:
    break

# determine number of leading zeros
length = len(str(number))
zeros = 0
if length == 1:
    zeros = 3
elif length == 2:
    zeros = 2
elif length == 3:
    zeros = 1

# add leading zeros to final number
final_number = ""
for i in range(zeros):
    final_number += '0'

# add user-provided number to end of string
final_number += str(number)

print(final_number)
```

but my loop seems a little bit problem because 3digits can only use number<1000? and when user input some digits like 32AB, how to adjust it ? anyone can please check my codes and correct it? thank you so much.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67387980/12693728 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this. Here we use len to find how many digits a number has. But first we have to convert user input to a string.

```
while True:
    try: 
        number = str(input("Please enter four digits: "))
        int(number)
        if len(number) > 4:
            print("Incorrect")
        elif len(number) < 4:
            print("Incorrect")
        else:
            break
    except ValueError: 
        print("Please input only numerical values ")
```

Comment: but how to add some output like Enter four digits: q  <- This quits the program. ?